# How To Update Common Properties of Different Type of Entityobjects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

My tables have common columns like  'Operation_Time' , 'Create_User' . 
Instead of writing update codes for many types of my entity objects -that is personels,adress etc.- i want to write a static method that will take an entityobject and will update its target fields . With Dataset, DataTable this was very easy .

```
function updateEntityObjectsCommonFields(EntityObject obj) 
 {  /// just i guess
    obj.Fields["Create_Usr"] = Session.Usr;
    obj.Fields["Operation_Time"] = DateTime.Now;
    obj.Fields["Last_Op_Usr"] = Session.Usr;
 }

/// usage
updateEntityObjectsCommonFields(Person) ;
updateEntityObjectsCommonFields(Adres)    
updateEntityObjectsCommonFields(Application) ; ;
```

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your entities implement a common interface which specifies the fields you need and write your update function in terms of this interface.

```
public interface IAuditEntity
{
    User CreateUsr { get; set;}
    DateTime OperationTime { get; set;}
    User LastOperationUser { get; set;}
}

 public void UpdateEntityObjectsCommonFields(IAuditEntityobj) 
 {  /// just i guess
    obj.CreateUsr  = Session.Usr;
    obj.OperationTime  = DateTime.Now;
    obj.LastOperationUser  = Session.Usr;
 }
```

You can let them implement the interface by modifying your [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520) (if it applies to all entities) or by letting specific entities implement your interface in the [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbx7zzdd.aspx) file.

Comment: Thanks Wouter . I will try the solution but what will happen when I update the entity model ? will it overwrite all my interface relations ? Any solution for this ?

Comment: If you would write your code in the file generated by Visual Studio, then it would be overwritten. That's why I mentioned looking into T4 (so you can change the code generation really easy and add your Interface) or by using the partial class (= extending a generated class in another code file so it won't be overwritten when regenerating your code)